# Dependent Typing style Equality Proofs in Scala

Tags: scala, type-systems, dependent-type

Is it possible to implement an equality proof in Scala?

In the book Type Driven Development with Idris it gives an example of how the equality proof type could be defined.

```
data (=): a -> b -> Type where
    Refl : x = x
```

My first instinct to convert this to Scala is something like this.

```scala
sealed trait EqualityProof[A, B]
final case class EqualityProofToken[T](value: T) extends EqualityProof[value.type, value.type]
```

However this requires I prove to the compiler that the two objects I want to compare are the same exact instance. Ideally this would work for equal objects that are different instances, though that may be asking too much. Is this just a limitation that can't be avoided due to Scala allowing mutable data? Is there any way to implement this properly? If not is there a workaround other than using asInstanceOf to lie to the compiler (or a way to limit the use of asInstanceOf)?

Update: It seems there is some confusion about the definition of the problem so I'm adding a more complete Idris example.

```
data EqNat : (num1 : Nat) -> (num2 : Nat) -> Type where
 Same : (num : Nat) -> EqNat num num

sameS : (k : Nat) -> (j : Nat) -> (eq : EqNat k j) -> EqNat (S k) (S j)
sameS k k (Same k) = Same (S k)

checkEqNat : (num1 : Nat) -> (num2 : Nat) -> Maybe (EqNat num1 num2)
checkEqNat Z Z = Just (Same 0)
checkEqNat Z (S k) = Nothing
checkEqNat (S k) Z = Nothing
checkEqNat (S k) (S j) = case checkEqNat k j of
                              Nothing => Nothing
                              Just eq => Just (sameS _ _ eq)
```

At this point the EqNat instance can be used to perform operations that require equal values such as zipping to lists of lengths that have been proven equal.

Comment: I wonder if class tags or type tags could make this work... Interesting question in any case!

Comment: Scala *does* have dependent typing in the form of dependent method types and path-dependent types. However, the encoding is not 1:1, you cannot just map Idris/Agda/Coq/HOL/Guru/Epigram style dependent types to Scala, you have to encode them. I am far from knowledgeable enough to tell you how. From my limited understanding, the "dependent" part is encoded using path-dependent types and dependent method types, and the "proof" (or "search") part is encoded using implicit resolution (which provides the necessary backtracking).

Comment: It's not quite clear to me: does the Idris thing prove that the singleton types of two values will be equal, so that you have a compile time proof that 2 values are equal? Or does it merely prove that any two types are equal, like in scala `def equal[A,B](a: A, b: B)(implicit ev: A =:= B)`?

Comment: You should be able to prove at runtime that values are equal. My understanding is you return an optional proof value instead of a boolean.

Comment: @MI3Guy Did you mean 'at compile time'?

Comment: No, at runtime. There's no point in just proving that compile time values are equal.

Comment: Then what's the point of the Idris proof? I'm not quite following anymore.

Comment: One common example is to prove the length of two lists is the same before performing a zip operation. In Idris, this can be done with a list entered by the user at runtime.

Comment: I think your comments about wanting to prove equality at runtime are confusing. You don't have to prove equality at runtime, you can just check it; Scala is perfectly capable of that, even PHP is! What *you* want to do, is you want to be able to prove *at compile time* that the *runtime values* are equal. Going with your example of `zip`, you want to be able to prove *at compile time* that the two lists have the same length *at runtime*. **That's** what dependent typing provides you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple translation from Idris is quite straightforward, you just use an implicit to provide the compile-time proof:

```
sealed trait Equality[A, B]

case class Refl[A]() extends Equality[A, A]

case object Equality {

  implicit def refl[B]: Equality[B, B] = Refl[B]()
}
```

It's placed in the companion object, so it will be always in scope when you're requiring an implicit of the `Equality` type.

You can find a more involved definition of such equality-type in the [ohnosequences/cosas](https://github.com/ohnosequences/cosas/blob/master/src/main/scala/cosas/equality.scala) library together with some [tests/examples](https://github.com/ohnosequences/cosas/blob/master/src/test/scala/cosas/EqualityTests.scala). (disclaimer: I'm one of maintainers)

Comment: As far as I can see this proves type equality, not value equality.

Comment: What do you mean by "proving" value equality. The question was about type equality and this is what your Idris example describes. You can _compare_ values, but in _runtime_.

Comment: The Idris example is perfectly capable of proving value equality. It sounds like there isn't any way to do this in Scala.

Comment: I think there's some confusion about types/values. I will extend my answer later today.

Comment: You can prove about equality between values in Idris. That's what's special about Idris!

Comment: @盛安安 Yes, but you prove equality at compile time, by using (dependent) types, as far as I understand it. You prove equality at runtime by `if (a == b)`.